# Как запретить растягивать блок содержимым?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Как запретить растягивать flex блок содержимым? Должна появляться прокрутка как на картинке, высота левого блока тянется в зависимости от высоты правого, а не как в примере.

```css
.min-width-300 {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.o-y-auto {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-dark p-2 d-flex">
  <div class="bg-primary p-2 min-width-300">
    <div class="h-100 o-y-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quisquam praesentium iste quod, sapiente consequuntur aut facilis facere excepturi, dolor animi. Similique, delectus. Ad aliquam placeat et. Provident reiciendis unde voluptatem, et, modi
      voluptatum quia libero saepe omnis quae autem.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-info p-2 fex-grow-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum quas voluptate eum porro eaque quod doloribus fugit dicta aliquam debitis deserunt molestiae, obcaecati, at ducimus maxime quaerat sequi ipsam veniam amet? A et debitis vero ducimus exercitationem
    nesciunt, placeat voluptate saepe facilis? Fugit necessitatibus corporis hic neque, quia exercitationem dolore odio quam reprehenderit, libero nobis blanditiis dolor corrupti et, iure nemo fugiat vero debitis aperiam illum! Odio, maxime similique!
    uaerat sequi ipsam veniam amet? A et debitis vero ducimus exercitationem nesciunt, placeat voluptate saepe facilis? Fugit necessitatibus corporis hic neque, quia exercitationem dolore odio quam reprehenderit, libero nobis blanditiis dolor corrupti
    et, iure nemo fugiat vero debitis aperiam illum! Odio, maxime similique!Incidunt, sint suscipit expedita ad rerum soluta ea fuga? Fugit cupiditate voluptatem suscipit dolorem corporis unde sequi atque officiis perferendis sint, asperiores qui quaerat
    maxime magnam expedita illum quam inventore perspiciatis.</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пример https://codepen.io/pikiviki/pen/pKpYLE

Answer (score -1):

### Решение:

Можно обернуть текст правого блока в параграф. И при загрузке или изменении окна браузера вызывать присвоение высоты параграфа для левого блока:

```
function changeSecondBlock() {
  let mainBlock = document.querySelector('.mainBlock').clientHeight;

  document.querySelector('.secondBlock').style.maxHeight = mainBlock +'px';
}

changeSecondBlock();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  changeSecondBlock();
});
```

### Пример:

```js
function changeSecondBlock() {
  let mainBlock = document.querySelector('.mainBlock').clientHeight;

  document.querySelector('.secondBlock').style.maxHeight = mainBlock + 'px';
}

changeSecondBlock();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  changeSecondBlock();
});
```

```css
.min-width-300 {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.o-y-auto {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-dark p-2 d-flex">
  <div class="bg-primary p-2 min-width-300">
    <div class="h-100 o-y-auto secondBlock">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quisquam praesentium iste quod, sapiente consequuntur aut facilis facere excepturi, dolor animi. Similique, delectus. Ad aliquam placeat et. Provident reiciendis unde voluptatem, et, modi
      voluptatum quia libero saepe omnis quae autem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quisquam praesentium iste quod, sapiente consequuntur aut facilis facere excepturi, dolor animi. Similique, delectus. Ad aliquam placeat
      et. Provident reiciendis unde voluptatem, et, modi voluptatum quia libero saepe omnis quae autem.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-info p-2 fex-grow-1">
    <p class='mainBlock'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum quas voluptate eum porro eaque quod doloribus fugit dicta aliquam debitis deserunt molestiae, obcaecati, at ducimus maxime quaerat sequi ipsam veniam amet? A et debitis vero ducimus
      exercitationem nesciunt, placeat voluptate saepe facilis? Fugit necessitatibus corporis hic neque, quia exercitationem dolore odio quam reprehenderit, libero nobis blanditiis dolor corrupti et, iure nemo fugiat vero debitis aperiam illum! Odio,
      maxime similique! uaerat sequi ipsam veniam amet? A et debitis vero ducimus exercitationem nesciunt, placeat voluptate saepe facilis? Fugit necessitatibus corporis hic neque, quia exercitationem dolore odio quam reprehenderit, libero nobis blanditiis
      dolor corrupti et, iure nemo fugiat vero debitis aperiam illum! Odio, maxime similique!Incidunt, sint suscipit expedita ad rerum soluta ea fuga? Fugit cupiditate voluptatem suscipit dolorem corporis unde sequi atque officiis perferendis sint, asperiores
      qui quaerat maxime magnam expedita illum quam inventore perspiciatis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```